# How to remap AltGr key in KDE 4.3.2?

Tags: linux, keymap, kde-4, altgr

I have enabled `altgr-intl` keyboard layout. How can I remap such that <kbd>Windows</kbd> key acts as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> instead of right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

KDE 4.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `xmodmap`to do this.

At a terminal, try entering:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Alt_R"
```

This command says: "When I press the key on the left (SuperL in this case), make it do what the key on the right does (AltR)." For that to work I'm assuming that the Windows key has the keysym `Super_L`; however it may not on your computer.

To find out the exact keysyms on your system, run `xev` from a terminal, and then press your Windows key and your Alt Gr key.

You should see part of the output along the lines of:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x6a, subw 0x0, time 24394571, (-167,-89), root:(384,232),
    state 0x48, keycode 115 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 113
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The part with **keysym** in brackets is what you're after.  This tells you what keysyms to use in the `xmodmap` command.

Once you have determined the `xmodmap` command you want to use, you might like to put it in your `.bashrc` file so that it is executed automatically every time you log in to KDE.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer. :-) I was able to remap the left Windows key. However, I had to use xev and the hexadecimal codes there. Thanks for the pointer. How can I remove the AltGr functionality from the right Alt key?

Comment: If depends what you want the `Alt Gr` key to do.  I guess you want it to do the same as a normal `Alt` key?  If so, use `xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_R = Alt_L"` (or whatever the equivalent keysyms are on your machine.)  If you want to remove functionality from `Alt Gr` altogether, you can use `xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_R = "`.  Note that you can use `keycode` as opposed to `keysym` (keycode information is also available in `xev`) -- you may need it if your keysyms get screwed up.